# Python: Removing sublists in a list if the string inside sublist starts with "- / 2......."

Tags: python, list, tuples, python-3.5

I have my

```
datacount= ([('mark / 222696_at', 19), ('jason / 210393_at', 15), ('mickey / 213880_at', 15), ('mo / 228649_at', 13), ('nick / 229481_at', 12), ('nikoo / 1553115_at', 12), ('- / 229613_at', 12)]
```

---

But I want to remove the tuple inside the list, which starts with the "- / 2" such as ('- / 229613_at', 12).

I tried this,

```
datacount = [x for x in datacount if x[0] not in ['str.startwith(- / 2) == True']]
```

---

but results such as ('- / 229613_at', 12), ('- / 232203_at', 11),('- / 244174_at', 6), ('- / 237146_at', 6) still show up.

Comment: `'str.startwith(- / 2) == True'` is a string, not a python expression...

Comment: Is `datacount` a tuple or list? Because it starts as a tuple and ends as a list...

Comment: I used this, it worked

datacount = [x for x in datacount if not x[0].startswith("- / ")]

Sorry, its list, with tuples inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
datacount = [x for x in datacount if not x[0].startswith('- / 2')]
```

Not exactly sure what you tried with `x[0] not in ['str.startwith(- / 2) == True']`, but it looks like some pattern that might occur in other languages. In Python, this essentially checks whether `x[0]` is equal to the string `'str.startwith(- / 2) == True'`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not that far off. The `in` check is where you seem to have a wrong mental model of what's happening.

I suggest the following list comprehension, featuring unpacking of the tuples for better legibility (instead of `x[0]` indexing):

```
>>> [(string, count) for string, count in datacount if not string.startswith('- / 2')]
[('mark / 222696_at', 19), ('jason / 210393_at', 15), ('mickey / 213880_at', 15), ('mo / 228649_at', 13), ('nick / 229481_at', 12), ('nikoo / 1553115_at', 12)]
```

Comment: Thank you all, I am new to python, its much faster compared to manual work in excel.